# Making Golems out of New materials

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, monster-design

For an upcoming Encounter, I want my group to to fight golems made out of paper.

I've looked at a few Nearly 2d monsters, such as a Palimpsest, or a Rug of Smothering, bit I haven't found quite the right fit for this encounter.

I have considered applying a template to a preexisting stat block, but I haven't found something to work as a large-sheet-of-paper for a base.

Because of how many I'm expecting, the construct should probably be weaker than the average golem. They need to be resilient, but not unstoppable.

The intent is for them to be obtrusive, but not the focus of the encounter since the party will need to be protecting an NPC, and be chased by a boss monster.

The Paper Golems will be set dressing to emphasize the theme of the encounter, and encourage the party on less "charge for the middle" kind of tactics.

If I need to expound on any specifics I am willing, I just need to focus on the Paper Golem so it feels authentic.

Tldr, I don't posses a stat block for a construct or golem made solely of paper. I am trying to make one. I would like advice on the process.

Comment: It isn’t clear what the issue is here. What exactly is the problem you’re having? Why can’t/haven’t you just picked a suitable golem to reflavor?

Comment: Because the weakest golems aren't effective trash mobs, it isn't clear why or how they possess multiple immunities. If I'm making a construct, or golem out of paper, how do I make it feel like they're fighting paper and not clay?

Comment: The most answerable way to do this would probably be to take a weak golem, reskin it, remove unneeded defences, and ask for a [tag:homebrew-review].

Comment: Sorey, the Update did nothing to make it less opinion based

Comment: We dont really do “homebrew this for me” questions here. As Molot said, if you’ve got something you’ve already made, we can evaluate it against your objectives for it, but we don’t build them from scratch.

Comment: So, asking for advice is out of bounds?

Comment: @Xisnue precise questions, where answers can be easily judged right or wrong, are ok. Open ended questions that invite further discussion, are not. Here, answers would provoke people to review the homebrew in comments. Stack Exchange format is not designed for this. Discussions like that are something that forum format supports way better.

Comment: So I could submit a stat block for review, give a rough idea what my party is capable of, and inquire what adjusting is needed to fill the roll of a trash mob?